# R package "zipcode," clean.zipcodes

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 9 digit zip codes.

```
> df
           a
1  900403416
2  900403416
3  900403416
4  900403416
5  900403416
6  900403416
7  900403416
8  900403416
9  900403416
10 900403416
```

I tried to make these zip codes as 5 digit zip code, but seems like cleaning didn't work by using "clean.zipcodes(df$a)"

```
>library(zipcode)
> df$zip1 = clean.zipcodes(df$a)
> df

           a      zip1
1  900403416 900403416
2  900403416 900403416
3  900403416 900403416
4  900403416 900403416
5  900403416 900403416
6  900403416 900403416
7  900403416 900403416
8  900403416 900403416
9  900403416 900403416
10 900403416 900403416
```

Does anyone have any idea why clean.zipcodes(df$a) is not working?

Comment: what is a 'clean' zip code? Take a look inside `clean.zipcodes` by typing it into the console and you'll see all the `gsub` commands it's using. Then test if they're doing what you think it 'should' do to generate your 'clean' zip codes

Comment: Yours aren't in any of the forms that the function expects. You could easily just use substring to get the first five digits.

Comment: sub("(^.{5]).({4}$)", "\\1", df$a)